# How to export datagridview to Excel with checkboxes

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, xls

I have this code to export a Winforms datagridview:

```
public static void SaveToCSV(DataGridView dGV, string strNomArchivo)
{
    string stOutput = "";

    // Export titles:
    string sHeaders = "";

    for (int j = 0; j < dGV.Columns.Count; j++) 
    {
        if (dGV.Columns[j].Visible == true)
            sHeaders = sHeaders.ToString() + Convert.ToString(dGV.Columns[j].HeaderText) + "\t";
    }

    stOutput += sHeaders + "\r\n";

    // Export data.
    for (int i = 0; i < dGV.RowCount - 1; i++)
    {
        string stLine = "";

        for (int j = 0; j < dGV.Rows[i].Cells.Count; j++) 
        {
            if (dGV.Columns[j].Visible == true)
                stLine = stLine.ToString() + Convert.ToString(dGV.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value) + "\t";
        }

        stOutput += stLine + "\r\n";
    }

    Encoding utf16 = Encoding.GetEncoding(1254);
    byte[] output = utf16.GetBytes(stOutput);

    FileStream fs = new FileStream(strNomArchivo, FileMode.Create);

    BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs);
    bw.Write(output, 0, output.Length); //write the encoded file
    bw.Flush();
    bw.Close();

    fs.Close();
}
```

How I do to export Winforms datagridview to an Excel file preserving the checkboxes? I need to show similar checkboxes in the xls from datagridview. Thanks in advance.

Comment: DataGridView is how you render the data as a table, not the data itself.  You can use a library like EPPlus to create real Excel files from the data using eg just `sheet.Cells.LoadFromCollection(muList)` or `sheet.Cells.LoadFromDataTable(myTable)`

Comment: The encoding tricks are unnecessary too. C# strings are already UTF16. And 1254 is *definitely* not Unicode. There's no reason to use such code. A simple. `File.WriteAllText(somePath,someText)` would be enough. If you want to use a specific encoding you can pass it as the third parameter, eg `File.WriteAllText(somePath,someText,Encoding.GetEncoding(1254))`

Comment: One way would be to use the ballot box characters `"\u2611"` and `"\u2610"`.